# Error en sumar dígitos de un número

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa que sume los dígitos de un numero pero no me da el resultado espero al colocar un número de 11 cifras.

- Código

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int extNum, sumDigit = 0, numEntero;
    cout << "Ingrese un numero entero: ";
    cin >> numEntero;
    while(numEntero != 0) {
        extNum = numEntero % 10;
        numEntero /= 10;
        sumDigit += extNum;
    }
    cout << "La suma de los digitos es: " << sumDigit << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- Entrada: **20483031154**
- Resultado esperado: **31**
- Resultado obtenido: **46**

[image: salida del programa]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El número posiblemente no entre en el tamaño de un `int` en tu arquitectura.

El tipo `int` por defecto suele ser de 32 bits. El número que has introducido, al ponerlo en binario requiere 35 bits, por lo que no cabe y se habrá producido algún tipo de truncación, alterando el número guardado y por tanto el resultado.

Puedes cambiar a un entero de 64 bits (si tu arquitectura lo permite) con la declaración:

```
    unsigned long long int extNum, numEntero;
    int sumDigit = 0;                // Este no necesitamos que sea tan grande
```

Con esto ya podrás usar números tan grandes como `18446744073709551615`, pero más allá de éste volverás a encontrar problemas.

Comment: +1, muchas gracias